# sqlite логика подключения к базе данных

Tags: sqlite3, sqlite

Есть база данных sqlite. В данный момент подключения к базе происходят только по необходимости, т.е. потребовалось получить данные - коннект, выборка, дисконнект. Соответственно если на форме несколько разных видов данных, то для каждого из них выполняются эти 3 операции.

Для примера: с формы заводим информацию о кошке. На форме `combobox'ы` с выбором породы, окраски, питомника. Для заполнения каждого `combobox` вызывается подключение, выборка, отключение.

Правильно ли так делать? Либо лучше при запуске приложения коннектиться к базе и держать подключение до закрытия приложения?

Comment: по моему опыту, создается метод, в нем коннект, выборка, дисконект, возвращение выборки. Опять же непонятно, как и на что реагируют ваши "несколько разных видов данных".

Comment: @ТимурВалиев добавил пример в вопрос.

Comment: если "породы, окраски, питомники" в разных таблицах, логично их и извлекать отдельно - это добавляет гибкости и в том случае если понадобится добавить значение в таблицу, в таком случае моё мнение, да, правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Правильно ли так делать? Либо лучше при запуске приложения коннектиться к базе и держать подключение до закрытия приложения?

Если сервер БД и клиент на одном хосте - сойдёт и так, коннект на каждый чих. Если же посередине сетевой обмен, лучше одно соединение на пачку запросов.

В большинстве случаев более разумен промежуточный подход - одно соединение для одного объекта (той же формы), а не для всего приложения. Создать при открытии формы, убить при закрытии.

Comment: Немного уточню. С одной формы могут изменять данные нескольких таблиц. Реализовано классами, каждой таблице соответствует свой класс. С формы передаётся информация в конкретный класс, а он уже сам общается с БД. В таком случае Вы рекомендуете подключение создавать при запуске формы и передавать его в классы, а не запускать в каждом классе своё?

Comment: Нет, каждый отвечает за себя и только за себя. Если с БД общается класс, то именно он и должен обеспечивать СВОЁ общение с БД, а не надеяться на то, что ему предоставит вызывающая его форма. Равно как и форма не должна заниматься проблемами вызываемого ей класса. Т.е., например, инстанс объекта в конструкторе открывает соединение, процедуры объекта его использует, а в деструкторе соединение закрывается. Плюс обработка события разрыва соединения - например, восстановлением или открытием нового.

Comment: Тогда еще вопрос :) У меня в данный момент реализовано так: конструктор открывает соединение, получает данные, закрывает. Каждое свойство класса при изменении также открывает соединение, изменяет таблицу, закрывает. Лучше открывать в конструкторе, а закрывать в деструкторе? В отношении sqlite это не будет источником проблем, т.к. sqlite не очень любит многопользовательский доступ?

Comment: Понятия не имею, как лучше. Что любит sqlite - вообще не в курсе. Но просто логика диктует, что "каждый за себя". А будет этот каждый на любой чих новый коннект открывать, или будет всё время пользоваться одним - это уже сам решай. Как скажешь, так и будет. Неправильно скажешь - все грабли за твой счёт.

Comment: так в вопросе указан `sqlite`, соответственно и хочу узнать, как лучше работать именно с ним.

Comment: Тогда чётко оговаривайте ситуацию. Кто работает с этой БД? Одно приложение, синхронная работа компонентов? Одно приложение, асинхронная работа компонентов? Несколько копий приложения в рамках одной копии ОС? Несколько копий приложения, в т.ч. есть удалённые клиенты? В первом случае даже одно соединение на приложение - нормально. Во втором - соединение на объект или на запрос. В остальных соединение на запрос. Так минимизируются возможные коллизии. А поскольку приложение интерактивное, то производительность запросов неприоритетна.